# Pass image source url as string to component

Tags: angular

I have this component:

icon.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
   selector: "icon",
   styleUrls: ["dist/app/components/shared/subcomponents/icon.component.css"],
   templateUrl: "dist/app/components/shared/subcomponents/icon.component.html",
})
export class IconComponent {
   @Input() public imgSrc: string;
}
```

icon.component.html:

```
<img src="{{ imgSrc }}" class="pull-xs-left icon card-icon" />
```

So the imgSrc needs to be passed to it by the parent in html.

usage in another component:

```
<icon [imgSrc]="dist/resources/images/heart.png"></icon>
```

error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in dist/app/components/results-page/result-image.component.html:3:12 caused by: Cannot read property 'png' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'png' of undefined
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ResultImageComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/FindPageModule/ResultImageComponent/component.ngfactory.js:93:113)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9355:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9448:48)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ResultDetailsComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/FindPageModule/ResultDetailsComponent/component.ngfactory.js:318:20)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9355:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9448:48)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ResultsComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/FindPageModule/ResultsComponent/component.ngfactory.js:127:20)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9355:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9448:48)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_FindPageComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/FindPageModule/FindPageComponent/component.ngfactory.js:91:19)
```

I have tried to escape the `.` like:

```
[imgSrc]="dist/resources/images/heart\.png"
```

However that lead to the html parse error `\`.

How do I pass the url string to `<icon>` without getting errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `[]`. This will cause angular to try and evaluate the value you pass to it. Without the brackets, the value will get treated like a string, which is what you want

```
imgSrc="dist/resources/images/heart.png"
```

Or if you use the brackets, then you need to use quotes, so angular evaluated it as a string

```
[imgSrc]="'dist/resources/images/heart.png'"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you require to pass it as a string when you could use it as **`binding`** follow,

```
<img [src]="imgSrc"     //<<<----- removed curly braces and added [] around src attribute
     class="pull-xs-left icon card-icon" />
```

in **`child component`** use it likem

```
<whateverChild [imgSrc]="imgSrc"></whateverChild>
```

here I'm wrapping imgSrc (or use other name if angular2 doesn't allow you to use the same name as not sure) by `[]` which allows me to use/pass **binding value**. If I know string value, I can also use it like

```
<whateverChild imgSrc="'static path/string'"></whateverChild>
```

this syntax will only pass **`static string`** as it is wrapped by single quote and other side I don't force angular2 pass value with binding value that is`[]`.

So in short : `[]` -`for angualr2 bindings`  and `no []` -`for static value`

For some clarification after reading above post if you plan to pass imgSrc like this,

```
 <whateverChild [imgSrc]="'imgSrc'"></whateverChild>
```

then it will pass `imgSrc` as a string and not the value it contains.

I hope you get it what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I may not understand. Won't `<whateverChild [imgSrc]="imgSrc"></whateverChild>  ` have the same issue I had? Are you using `[]` to pass an image source to the child in this example?

Comment: I believe you want to bind same `img` in child too. You can use it. wrapping `src` or `imgSrc` by `[]` tells compiler to use binding(dynamic) value and not static value.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure whether it works as you use same name `imgSrc`. For that you can play with it and change the name if name conflict happens. other than name, it will work as expected. what other answer suggests is to pass value as a static value by wrapping it with single quote(`'`).

Comment: I am just wanting to pass the static string. Thanks for the info though.